# Leaving a mark on a textured wall in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering

I don't know the actual term of this technique but how do I apply a texture (say a bullet-hole texture) somewhere in my 3D map (where my character shot)?

Here's what I'm talking about:
[image: csgo]

Comment: I believe it's called a _decal_.